# How to convert Solr bf based query to bq based syntax?

Tags: solr, pysolr

Current working query:

```
qf = field1^30 field2^30 field3^10
bf = sum(num1,num2) // num1 & num2 are integer fields in each document
```

The bf additive boost gets applied to all fields, I would want to exclude `field3` from this,
how can this `qf` & `bf` syntax be changed to `qf` & `bq` syntax so that boost can only be applied to `field1` and `field2` and not `field3`